# Explode Spark Daraframe Avro Map into flat format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, avro, spark-avro

I am using Spark Shell v_1.6.1.5.

I have the following Spark Scala Dataframe:

```
val data = sqlContext.read.avro("/my/location/*.avro")
data.printSchema
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- stuff: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- created: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- lastModified: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- . . .
```

What's the exact syntax to 'explode it' into the following flat format (discarding possible null values): `[id, key, value]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using a `udf` and `explode`.

However we do not know the class of the values in the map because this information is inferred and is not available as an explicit class. In order to overcome this issue we can "shadow" the inferred class by making a case class with an identical class signature. Spark then treats these classes identically because both the inferred class and our shadow class are converted into an identical `StructType`

Here is an example (the case class `value` is a standin for the inferred class that we do not know).

```
scala> case class value(created: Long, lastModified: Long)
defined class value

scala> val myDF = Seq((1, Map("a" -> value(1L,2L), "b" -> value(3L,4L))), (2, Map("c" -> value(5L,6L), "d" -> value(6L,7L)))).toDF("id", "stuff")
myDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, stuff: map<string,struct<created:bigint,lastModified:bigint>>]

scala> myDF.show
+---+--------------------+
| id|               stuff|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|Map(a -> [1,2], b...|
|  2|Map(c -> [5,6], d...|
+---+--------------------+


scala> myDF.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- stuff: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- created: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- lastModified: long (nullable = false)


scala> case class shadowOfValue(created: Long, lastModified: Long)
defined class shadowOfValue

scala> val explodeUDF = udf( (map: Map[String, shadowOfValue]) => map.toVector)
explodeUDF: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(_1,StringType,true), StructField(_2,StructType(StructField(created,LongType,false), StructField(lastModified,LongType,false)),true)),true),Some(List(MapType(StringType,StructType(StructField(created,LongType,false), StructField(lastModified,LongType,false)),true))))

scala> var newDF = myDF.withColumn("TMP", explode(explodeUDF($"stuff"))).drop("stuff")
newDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, TMP: struct<_1: string, _2: struct<created: bigint, lastModified: bigint>>]

scala> newDF = newDF.withColumn("key", $"TMP".apply("_1")).withColumn("value", $"TMP".apply("_2"))
newDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, TMP: struct<_1: string, _2: struct<created: bigint, lastModified: bigint>> ... 2 more fields]

scala> newDF = newDF.drop("TMP")
newDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, key: string ... 1 more field]

scala> newDF.show
+---+---+-----+
| id|key|value|
+---+---+-----+
|  1|  a|[1,2]|
|  1|  b|[3,4]|
|  2|  c|[5,6]|
|  2|  d|[6,7]|
+---+---+-----+


scala> newDF.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- created: long (nullable = false)
 |    |-- lastModified: long (nullable = false)
```

Comment: thanks! I updated my question while you were typing your answer. I have a Map[string, struct], what should I use instead of String?

Comment: Hmm, just had to make it harder :P Let me think about it

Comment: @Gevorg The custom struct adds a kink. Is it defined anywhere in your code? I need to have the value type in my `udf`.

Comment: It is not defined explicitely. I believe that it is derived automatically from the avro schema of the input files.

Comment: @Gevorg yeah I was hoping it wouldn't be derived

Comment: In the Java generated Avro class it's a custom Object (think of a generic class Person for instance)

Comment: @Gevorg Yeah I need to specify the type in the parameter list of the UDF (`Map[String, NEEDTHISTYPE]`). If the class were defined locally (like a Person class), I could plug that in but since I can't pull the actual type from the schema I don't think that a UDF will work here

Comment: Is there anything that can be done if we imagine that the custom class contains only 2 fields 'created', and 'lastModified'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128206/discussion-between-evan058-and-gevorg).